# Can i create scenes (menu, highscore and game) without using the Composer library?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, lua, coronasdk

I am working to a simple mobile game (the github link is below).
I copied most of the game mechanism from a blog and tried to edit it to make it prettier. Now i would like to add scenes but in Corona tutorial it looks like you have to edit all the code hence i can't do that because i don't know what many functions do. Is there a way to create scenes without editing the code but simply adding a few lines?

P.S. if there is a good good Samaritan here and he want to edit it for me i leave my github link

https://github.com/valeriova96/JumpJump.git

Comment: You can do this but it is hard and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you can do this in native android or iOS but it will be harder for you to do that because it needs more knowledge on Corona, if you tell me what you want to add or edit, maybe I can help you